# How to add vertical spacing between block elements, but not top and bottom

Tags: css

Say I have a bunch of P, LI, or DIV elements, with nothing between them.  I want to control the vertical spacing between them, so they don't fit so tightly.  But I don't want to add any space top and bottom, since that is handled by the parent element and I don't need more.  Is there a simple way to do this that works for all block elements?

Say I've got something like this :

```
p {
  margin: 5px 0;
  }
```

and then

```
 <div>
   <p>1</p>
   <p>2</p>
   <p>3</p>
   <p>4</p>
 </div>
```

But I don't want 5px above p 1, or below p 4, since the div already has padding and I don't want to go messing with that.  I just want the 10px between p 1 and p 2, p 2 and p 3, etc.

I'm sure I could do something kludgy (and I have many times), but am looking for something cleaner that I don't have to do a lot of special-casing for this common situation.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you have tried? Just the text is not enough to understand your problem.

Comment: sorry it was unclear, edited.

Comment: The easiest would be to use `p:last-item { margin: 0; }`

Comment: @Starx yeah that's probably easiest, but your answer that I accepted below is the elegant approach that I knew had to exist. :)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use adjacent selectors

```
p + p { margin-top: 10px; }
```

Basically the concept is that, if a `p` comes after another `p` give 10px margin in between.

You usage is something similar to

```
p + p, li + li, div + div { 
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done using `:last-child` or `:first-child`

Here is an example:

```
p, li, div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p:last-child, li:last-child, div:last-child {
    margin-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: it's better if you put this in your previous answer :)

Comment: @sandeep, Actually see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice), its a valid second answer

Comment: I use stackoverflow from an year now & i never saw a person give two answers for same question. They add the other alternative in there same answer.

Comment: @sandeep, No offence, but have you even bothered to read the post I link. It is perfectly alright to post multiple answer. Just needs to have a valid reason.

Comment: The most popular answer on that question on meta to talks about being very distinct (very subjective) and @sandeep might not feel that these two answers were very distinct.  If you look further you will see that jeff-attwood is not of the camp that thinks a single user should answer twice.  It would seem that everyone is right on this issue right now since it is a personal opinion on when it is ok to split into two answers.  Thanks for the link btw :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [adjacent selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)s. You can define like this:

```
p + p{
 margin-top:0;
}
```

**OR**

```
p ~ p{
 margin-top:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p, li, div {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#parentID {
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that messiness is what I do now.  Hoping for a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

```
p { margin: 10px 0 0 0; }
p:first-child { margin: 0; }
```

That is, set a top margin of 10px for all `p` elements and other margins to zero, except for the first `p` element, for which you set even the top margin to zero.

This works more widely than many other approaches, which use contextual selectors that are not supported by old browsers. To get really maximal browser support, you would assign a class to the first `p` element in markup and use a class selector instead of `p:first-child`.

This is the simplest possible way, since CSS operates on elements, not on what’s between elements. So you need some way of distinguishing the first `p` element in a sequence of `p` elements.

Note that `p { margin: 5px 0; }` (mentioned in the question) would create vertical margins of 5px, not 10px, because adjacent vertical margins collapse.