# HTML: How can I make a series of checkboxes within a div wrap to the next line?

Tags: javascript, html, webforms, formatting

[image: add new tags]

So I have a database of cooking recipes, and I'm making a web form which will eventually connect to the database to add entries to it. One column in the database is "tags". The web form will show all the tags that have been used before (with checkboxes), and give the user the option to add a new tag which will appear as a new checkbox next to the existing ones.

PROBLEM #1:
Right now the tags are separated by 1 space, but I'd like them to be separated by a larger gap so that it looks better. What is the best way to do this?

PROBLEM #2:
As more tags are added, they will eventually reach the right edge of this fieldset. What is the best way to make them wrap to the next line and ensure that the space(s) between the new tag and the previous one are ignored? (Otherwise the new tag might be indented on the next line which I do not want!)

THE HTML CODE:

```
<p>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Tags:</legend>
        <span class="tags">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Dessert">Dessert  <input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Fast">Fast  <input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Entree">Entree
        </span>
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="addtag"><input type="submit" value="Add">
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</p>
```

THE JAVASCRIPT:

```
$("input[value='Add']").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    tagAdded = document.getElementById('addtag').value;
    if (tagAdded!=null && tagAdded.trim()!="") {
        //$('.tags').append('????????');
    }
 });
```

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to use left/right margins and css like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309408/how-to-add-vertical-spacing-between-block-elements-but-not-top-and-bottom.

Comment: @Eugene: But what will I be adding margins to?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your tags (like "Dessert") should be in a `<label>` tag so:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Dessert" id="tag-1"><label for="tag-1">Dessert</label>
```

If you click on the word now, it will activate the checkbox in front of it.

Then to make a bigger gap:
use CSS:

```
label{
    margin-right: 2em;
}
```

this will give a gap that is the size of 2 letters m between your labels

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the label for each checkbox in a  tag and  add right padding to the label.

Comment: But what about the tag on the far right of the fieldset? I wouldn't want that one to have right padding on it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can solve problem 1 & 2...

wrap each tag like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Dessert">Dessert
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper { margin-right:10px; float:left; }
```

Comment: But what about the tag on the far right of the fieldset? I wouldn't want that one to have right padding on it.

Comment: Also, wouldn't a line break automatically be placed before and after the div?

Comment: "Browsers always place a line break before and after the <div> element." -w3schools.
I suppose using a <span> instead of a <div> would solve that problem. But then the tag on the far right would still have an unnecessary space after it (this is a fencepost problem). I might be willing to overlook that though. :) I'm playing with it now to see if it looks okay!

Comment: there won't be any if you add `float:left;`, you can try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the markup so that the checkbox block is like this (note that there are other things to fix, e.g. you are now trying to put `fieldset` inside `p`, which is invalid and won’t work):

```
<div class="tags">
<label><input type="checkbox" ...>Dessert</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ...>Fast</label>
...
</div>
```

Use CSS code like this:

```
.tags { margin-left: -4em; }
.tags label { padding-left: 4em;  white-space: nowrap; }
```

I’m using large spacing just to make things clearer; 2em would probably suffice—just remember to make the negative left margin value match the padding value.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code this way

Html:

```
<p>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Tags:</legend>
        <span class="tags">
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Dessert"> Dessert</p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Fast"> Fast</p>
            <p> <input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="Entree"> Entree</p>
        </span>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="addtag"><input type="submit" value="Add">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</p>​
```

Javascript:

```
$("input[value='Add']").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    tagAdded = document.getElementById('addtag').value;
    if (tagAdded!=null && tagAdded.trim()!="") {
        $('.tags').append('<p> <input type="checkbox" name="tags" value="' + tagAdded.trim() + '" /> ' + tagAdded.trim() + '</p>');
    }
 });​
```

css:

```
div { clear:both; }
.tags p {
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px;    
}
```

​